# MachineKey setting for AntiForgeryToken in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, machinekey

I was deploying my asp MVC 5 web site in Azure Web Site. Everything was fine until I tried to manage my account (changging the password), it gave an error like this:

***The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the  configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.***

I was using Asp Identity, so all the code is built in. I have been searching the solution and found two possibilities:

1) It is because there are two @html.antiforgerytoken. One belongs to the MANAGE controller form, and the other belongs to the login partial view int he navigation bar. I tried to exclude the login partial view, but the error persisted, so I concluded that problem might not be it.

2) As the error says, maybe it is about MACHINE KEY. I tried to input  setting to the web config. There are two popular ways to generate this machine key, fist is using ISS and the second is using third party. I wanted to use the ISS, but my ISS8 is not showing a modul to see the machine key which is weird that I could not find any solution for it. Then I tried the third party, and created something like this:

```
<machineKey validationKey="4359B782C08EF91E2AA6CA8AD46C0D63BF323E97ABAA06FBDA1535A1FA1CD2B7702B2BACDC937074ED65FC16D3ECA0F674BBAC8675910AF921D301CA22343AA1" decryptionKey="1A956B2A0405EC07AEBEFBA40DA7E61E2E17F001B868D7507EB3F3CD2AFF060E" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

Then I redeployed my website but the error persisted. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You mention two anti-forgery tokens. Are two actually being submitted to the server, or is it just one?

Comment: Only one is submitted I guess, because the other one (the one in partial view) is doing nothing

Comment: If your `<form>` tag includes both anti forgery tokens, then it will submit two of them, which would result in this error.

Comment: Nope, the form is separated, one in the main view, a form to change the password, the second one is in partial view, to show the authentication of user (login/register/Manage/log off) in navigation bar. Lets say, I want to make machine key, is the one I showed above correct? or should be anything else? maybe the machinekey should be from ISS8?